# Trying to create required blank field in contact

Tags: html, css, forms, spam

I have discovered the idea of including an extra field in an html contact form, and then hiding it using CSS, so that spam will fill it out while humans will not. I have created this hidden field. My question is this:

How do I make it so that the field must be blank in order for the form to send? I have setup forms that display a message when a required field is missing, so I guess its like the opposite of this?

Comment: You could do this pretty easily with JavaScript, but most spam bots are not going to interpret JavaScript and will just build a request straight to your form URL. Can you not just ignore it on the back end if that value is non-empty?

Comment: I'm a visual designer who knows CSS, so this is all quite confusing to me. How would I ignore it on the back end? This would be in the contact-form-handler.php file I'm guessing? Is that a solution to the issue?

Comment: Yes it would be in the PHP script that handles the submitted form.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it per JavaScript:

```
function send(){
    if(document.getElementById(yourSendButton).value == "") // go on
    else //the field is filled
```

or per PHP

```
if($_POST["nameOfYourButton"] == ""){
    //input is acceptable
}
else{
    //PROBLEM
}
```

I suggest implementing both.